# Swift extension - Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Array'

Tags: ios, swift, collections, swift-extensions, type-alias

I have an API that returns a JSON array of objects.  I've setup the structure to look as follows:

```
typealias MyModels = [MyModel]

struct MyModel: Codable {
    let field1: String
    let field2: String
    let mySubModel: SubModel?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case field1 = "Field1"
        case field2 = "Field2"
        case mySubModel = "MySubModel"
    }
}

struct SubModel: Codable {
    let subModelField1: String
    let subModelField2: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case subModelField1 = "SubModelField1"
        case subModelField2 = "SubModelField2"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is add this extension, supplying a path var (the NetworkModel protocol provides some base functionality for API operations):

```
extension MyModels: NetworkModel {
    static var path = "the/endpoint/path"
}
```

I don't have any issues in other model/struct classes that I setup in this way when the base is an object or json key.  However, since this one is different and simply is an array, I get this error when I put that extension in the class:

> Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Array' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause

I've done some digging and tried a few things with a where clause on the extension, but I'm just a bit confused as to what it wants.  I'm sure it's something simple, but any thoughts on this?  If I need to go about it a different way with the typealias above, I'm fine with that.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error is basically telling you to do this:

```
extension Array : NetworkModel where Element == MyModel {
    static var path = "the/endpoint/path"
}
```

You can't simply make an extension of `[MyModel]`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yep you are correct that I meant to have the "s" in there (corrected now in my original post).  When I change it to have what you put here, I get 2 errors: "Closure expression is unused", and then I get an error on my static var: "Static properties may only be declared on a type".  Thoughts?

Comment: my apologies, I'm confused.  The static is a string var that we need for supplying the API path.  The above code doesn't compile as-is, and I'm not sure why yet.  Is the formatting incorrect, by chance?  It seems to think there is a closure on this line.  Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @svguerin3 I realised that my last comment was a mistake. Keep using `static`. I have edited the answer to include the exact code you need. Can you show what you have written?

Answer (score 0):

Although Sweeper answered the question appropriately based on the initial question, I wanted to provide an alternative approach, even if potentially slightly more complex.  This can be accomplished by overriding the Decodable side of things and manually putting the models into a list:

```
struct MyModels: Codable {
    var modelList: [MyModel] = []

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let metaType = (Account.self as Decodable.Type)

        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let subdecoder = try container.superDecoder()
            if let model = try metaType.init(from: subdecoder) as? MyModel {
                modelList.append(model)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyModel: Codable {
    let subModelField1: String
    let subModelField2: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case subModelField1 = "SubModelField1"
        case subModelField2 = "SubModelField2"
    }
}

extension MyModels: NetworkModel {
    static var path = "the/endpoint/path"
}
```